# How to delete Kubernetes PVC with status Lost

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, bitnami

On my kubernetes cluster, I mapped persistenet volumn but some how my cluster get restarted, and rabbitmq is failing to start,
So I try to delete the PVC using

`kubectl delete pvc pvc-475317d7-5c92-4aec-9187-5760424a2c02`
comamnd,

but it stucked in **Lost** status, now My deployment Pod is failing with error

```
could not find v1.PersistentVolume "pvc-475317d7-5c92-4aec-9187-5760424a2c02" (repeated 4 times)
```

when I execute `kubectl get pvc` it gives

```
NAME                                          STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
data-rabbitmq-0                               Lost     pvc-475317d7-5c92-4aec-9187-5760424a2c02   0                         do-block-storage   177d
data-rabbitmq-1                               Lost     pvc-17d19163-6112-49e8-b38a-18e62d677ee8   0                         do-block-storage   177d
```

Can someone please help me how to solve this ?

Thanks
Alpesh

Comment: try `kubectl delete pvc data-rabbitmq-0`

Comment: `pvc-475317d7-5c92-4aec-9187-5760424a2c02` is the volume name not the pvc name

Comment: Thanks @TummalaDhanvi this solve my issue, Thanks you very much for quick help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you should be doing is `kubectl delete pvc data-rabbitmq-0`

`pvc-475317d7-5c92-4aec-9187-5760424a2c02`  is the name of the volume (pv)

You will get a better understanding once you see the output of `kubectl get pv`